# How to Integrate Celery with Odoo ERP?

Tags: celery, integration, odoo

How can i integrate Celery with Odoo v8.0?

Have any of you already done it?

It must be done with extra module, not inside the core code.

Answer (score 0):

Just recently I landed a [patch for this in our fork of Odoo](https://github.com/merchise-autrement/odoo/tree/merchise-8.0-celeryapp).  It's still alpha and there are a couple of things we're working on yet. For instance:

- True task status notifications.
- Dismissing task results.

Notice this patch is based on a branch where we have introduced changes to the core of Odoo, so you may have to surgically extract the Celery integration.